# querying a CSV::Table to find item with most sales between two given dates in plain old ruby script

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

I am trying to find the highest sales between two given dates.

this is what my ad_report.csv file with headers:

```
date,impressions,clicks,sales,ad_spend,keyword_id,asin
2017-06-19,4451,1006,608,24.87,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
2017-06-18,5283,3237,1233,85.06,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
2017-06-17,0,0,0,21.77,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
...
```

Below is all the working code I have that returns the row with the highest value, but not between the given dates.

```
require 'csv'
require 'date'

# get directory of the current file
LIB_DIR = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# get the absolute path of the ad_report & product_report CSV
# and set to a var
AD_CSV_PATH = File.expand_path('data/ad_report.csv', LIB_DIR)
PROD_CSV_PATH = File.expand_path('data/product_report.csv', LIB_DIR)

# create CSV::Table for ad-ad_report and product_report CSV
ad_report_table = CSV.parse(File.read(AD_CSV_PATH), headers: true)
prod_report_table = CSV.parse(File.read(PROD_CSV_PATH), headers: true)

## finds the row with the highest sales
sales_row = ad_report_table.max_by { |row| row[3].to_i }
At this point I can get the row that has the greatest sale, and all the data from that row, but it is not in the excepted range.

Below I am trying to use range with the preset dates.

## range of date for items between
first_date = Date.new(2017, 05, 02)
last_date = Date.new(2017, 05, 31)
range = (first_date...last_date)

puts sales_row
```

below is sudo code of what I feel that I am supposed to do, but there is probably a better method.

```
## check for highest sales
## return sales if between date
## else reject col if 
## loop this until it returns date between
## return result
```

Comment: CSV is not a substitute for a database. Instead it's a file format used to transfer data between spreadsheets or databases. Searching or reading a CSV file to generate a report is a slow way to determine any sort of information. Eventually the CSV reading can cause problems once it's too big to fit into memory. I'd recommend looking into a DBM as even SQLite will make this task a lot faster and easier. Using an ORM will make your code a lot more flexible too; I recommend [Sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) but YMMV.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see where you make an attempt to compare against your date range. Please try writing that, then if you have a problem ask a question. As is your question is premature. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" help explain the process.

Comment: @theTinMan, in general I cannot disagree, but there may be situations where the CSV file is a given, produced by someone else, and is to be read only once, in which case it may not make sense to read it into a database and then extract the information of interest. Moreover, in this case there is no need to gulp the CSV file into memory; it can be read line-by-line.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Possibly in a reporting or summarizing situation where the file can be immediately thrown away and the summary passed on, but that's a situation I never encountered in way too many years. The summary would be generated rather than pass on in a CVS database dump. If the data was from inside an organization/company the data would be internally accessible from a DBM. Databases are SO much faster and could do that same lookup in a fraction of the time. It really sounds like a case for an XY-problem... "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)".

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating a range containing two dates and then use `Range#cover?` to test if the date is in the range:

```
range = Date.new(2015-01-01)..Date.new(2020-01-01)
rows.select do |row|
  range.cover?(Date.parse(row[1]))
end.max_by { |row| row[3].to_i }
```

Although the Tin Man is completely right in that you should use a database instead.

Comment: It is going pretty slow. Okay. I want to complete this solution and then I will try to use a database instead. Thanks!

Comment: What did you expect? You're parsing the worst format known to man and looping through a huge object in Ruby. Of course its slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtained the desired value as follows. I have assumed that the field of interest (`'sales'`) represents integer values. If not, change `.to_i` to `.to_f` below.

**Code**

```
require 'csv'

def greatest(fname, max_field, date_field, date_range)
  largest = nil
  CSV.foreach(fname, headers:true) do |csv|
    largest = { row: csv.to_a, value: csv[max_field].to_i } if
      date_range.cover?(csv[date_field]) &&
      (largest.nil? || csv[max_field].to_i > largest[:value])
  end
  largest.nil? ? nil : largest[:row].to_h
end
```

**Examples**

Let's first create a CSV file.

```
str =<<~END
date,impressions,clicks,sales,ad_spend,keyword_id,asin
2017-06-19,4451,1006,608,24.87,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
2017-06-18,5283,3237,1233,85.06,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
2017-06-17,0,0,0,21.77,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
2017-06-20,4451,1006,200000,24.87,UVOLBWHILJ,63N02JK10S
END
```

```
fname = 't.csv'
File.write(fname, str)
  #=> 263
```

Now find the record within a given date range for which the value of "sales" is greatest.

```
greatest(fname, 'sales', 'date', '2017-06-17'..'2017-06-19')    
  #=> {"date"=>"2017-06-18", "impressions"=>"5283", "clicks"=>"3237",
  #    "sales"=>"1233", "ad_spend"=>"85.06", "keyword_id"=>"UVOLBWHILJ",
  #    "asin"=>"63N02JK10S"} 
greatest(fname, 'sales', 'date', '2017-06-17'..'2017-06-25')
  #=> {"date"=>"2017-06-20", "impressions"=>"4451", "clicks"=>"1006",
  #   "sales"=>"200000", "ad_spend"=>"24.87", "keyword_id"=>"UVOLBWHILJ",
  #   "asin"=>"63N02JK10S"}
greatest(fname, 'sales', 'date', '2017-06-22'..'2017-06-25')    
  #=> nil
```

I read the file line-by-line (using [CSV#foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach)) to keep memory requirements to a minimum, which could be essential if the file is large.

Notice that, because the date is in "yyyy-mm-dd" format, it is not necessary to convert two dates to `Date` objects to compare them; that is, they can be compared as strings (e.g. `'2017-06-17' <= '2017-06-18' #=> true`).